# Integers and Fractions.

Tags: fractions, integers

Each of the numbers $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$ and $9$ is used once to fill in one of the
variables in the equation below to make it correct. Of the three fractions being added, what is the value of the largest one?

$\dfrac{1}{ab}+\dfrac{c}{de}+\dfrac{f}{gh}=1$

I have tried putting in different combinations of the numbers $2$ to $9$ in the blanks, but it's not leading me anywhere. Is there a smarter way to answer this question?

Comment: I can't see anything. Can you replace the blanks by variables $a,b,c,...$?

Comment: @TrầnThúcMinhTrí : Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited the question now.   :-)

Comment: @MathTise If $a=2$ and $b=3$, is $ab$ $6$ or $23$?

Comment: @TobyMak $ab=6$, but $\overline{ab}=23$.

Comment: @TobyMak since $\frac{1}{23}+\frac9{23}+\frac{8}{23} < 1$, you cannot interpret $ab$ as $23$

Comment: I suspect you need $c$ and $f$ to be $5$ and $7$ or the other way round

Comment: @Henry Did you read my mind? I already put that in my answer! (just kidding)

Comment: indeed since $degh+cabgh+fabde=abdegh$ we have $ab|degh$ and thus $a,b\ne{}5,7$. Same holds for $d,e,g,h$ and so since the formulas are the same we can assume $c=5, f=7$.

Answer (score 4):

Since no other numbers share a common divisor with $5$ and $7$, they must be in the numerator. Therefore, let $c = 5$ and $f = 7$:

$$\frac{1}{ab} + \frac{5}{de} + \frac{7}{gh} = 1$$

Let us start with the fraction with the biggest numerator: $\displaystyle \frac{7}{gh}$. However, $ \displaystyle \frac{7}{2 \cdot 3}$ already is greater than $1$.

After the next largest choice, $\displaystyle \frac{7}{2 \cdot 4}$, the numbers left over are $3, 6, 8, 9$. There are $\displaystyle {4 \choose 2} = 6$ possibilities, but since addition is communitative, there are only $3$ possibilities. These are:

$$\frac{1}{3 \cdot 6} + \frac{5}{8 \cdot 9} = \frac{1}{8}$$
$$\frac{1}{3 \cdot 8} + \frac{5}{6 \cdot 9} \ne \frac{1}{8}$$
$$\frac{1}{3 \cdot 9} + \frac{5}{6 \cdot 8} \ne \frac{1}{8}$$

Therefore, $$\frac{1}{3 \cdot 9} + \frac{5}{6 \cdot 8} + \frac{7}{2 \cdot 4} = 1, $$

and the value of the largest fraction is $\frac{7}{8}$.

Comment: Thank You very much for the explanation @Toby Mak.   Greatly appreciated ...   :-)

Comment: @MathTise No problem!